# What's the name of the algorithm to balance an acyclic graph?

Tags: algorithms, trees

Algorithms class was a such a long time ago and I can't remember the name of the algorithm to balance an acyclic graph.

Let's start with a graph that looks like this:

```
        1
        |
        2
        |
        3
      /   \
     4     7
    / \    |
   5   6   8
```

The solution to balancing this out would be:

```
        2                             3
       /  \                         / |  \
      1    3                       2  4   7 
          /  \        =>          /  / \  |
        4     7                  1  5   6 8
      /   \   |
     5     6  8
```

You rotate until the you have a root node whose branch's are the same length and your tree is at a minimum height.

What algorithm am I describing?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Height of every possible tree in a connected, undirected acyclic graph](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25628636/427192) and [A polynomial algorithm for balancing acyclic data flow graphs](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=177308&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel1%2F12%2F4475%2F00177308)

Comment: @DanPichelman Related, but not relevant in this context.

Comment: Rotating the tree sounds a little like the algorithm mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001676/balancing-a-bst the Day-Stout-Warren algorithm.

Comment: @ebyrob That looks pretty close. Whenever I get home I'll dig out my algorithms book and that will have the answer.

Comment: [Tree rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation), except that ... in your example, you don't seem to care about keeping the tree a binary tree. That might actually make your task much easier ...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to provide some more details in your description. Also, the example you give does not seem to be consistent (e.g. node 3 suddenly takes three children), whereas all other nodes seem to maintain at most two children.

Based on the little detail you provide, your rotation operations are similar to what's described in AVL tree rotations. See e.g. the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) page for more details.